# Handle Routing values in Lists

Tags: c#, list, recursion, routes

I'm handling a route mapper and I'm a bit off track. I got a large table of routes similar to the following:

sourceUrl -> destinationUrl

- a -> b
- y -> a
- q -> b
- d -> x
- b -> d
- r -> q
- c -> b

If I select the last node (d -> x), I would like to display the correct route or the related routes for the selected node. The table would look as follows:

- y -> a
- a -> b
- c -> b
- r -> q
- q -> b
- b -> d

Right now, Ive got a recursive method that returns a list, but I can't get the correct order. 
What I have right now is:

```
public List<RedirectNode> FindByDestinationUrl(string destinationUrl)
{
List<RedirectNode> nodeList = new List<RedirectNode>();
List<RedirectNode> temporalList = new List<RedirectNode>();
List<RedirectNode> helperList = new List<RedirectNode>();
try
{
    nodeList = _redirectManagerRepository.FindByDestinationUrl(destinationUrl);
    helperList = nodeList;
    if (nodeList.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (RedirectNode node in nodeList)
        {
            temporalList = FindByDestinationUrl(node.SourceUrl);
            if (temporalList != null)
            {
                helperList.AddRange(temporalList);
                helperList.Reverse();
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    nodeList = null;
    LoggingFactory.GetLogger().Log(CLASS + "FindByDestinationUrl. Error. " + ex.Message.ToString());
}
nodeList = helperList;
return nodeList;
}
```

I'm receiving the following route:

- a -> b
- c -> b
- q -> b
- y -> a
- b -> d

Comment: I gotta say this question is confusing me.  How is (d -> x) the last node? How are those other rates related to (d -> x) that they would be in the table for that node?  I don't understand your variable names.  In general names that state what they are DOING are preferred to names that state what they ARE.  HelperList should be... what should it be?  It's the same list as nodeList.  What is temporalList?  Is that supposed to be temporaryList?

Comment: @KyleW 
 d->x is the last node because if you follow the path, that would be the last node in a route.
y -> a -> b -> d -> x. 
nodeList will be the nodeList to return
temporalList will be the result of the recursion
helperList is used to hold the list values and then add it to nodeList. (I cannot Add elements to nodeList while I'm looping through it in the foreach, as it would send an InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified) 

I appreciate you taking some time on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do it a simple, full recursive way (https://dotnetfiddle.net/H2LAsr) that returns:

- y -> a
- a -> b
- r -> q
- q -> b
- c -> b
- b -> d
- d -> x

Not this order is what you want?

```
    //key is target, values are the sources
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, HashSet<string>> targetMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
    private static void Add(string source, string target)
    {
        var node = targetMap.GetOrAdd(target, new HashSet<string>());
        node.Add(source);
    }
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> FindTarget(string destination, bool recursive = true)
    {
        HashSet<string> node;
        if (targetMap.TryGetValue(destination, out node))
        {
            foreach (var source in node)
            {
                if (recursive)
                {
                    foreach (var child_route in FindTarget(source))
                    {
                        yield return child_route;
                    }
                }
                yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(source, destination);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        Add("a", "b");
        Add("y", "a");
        Add("q", "b");
        Add("d", "x");
        Add("b", "d");
        Add("r", "q");
        Add("c", "b");
        foreach (var route in FindTarget("x"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", route.Key, route.Value);
        }

    }
```